# Repetition and Refrain in literature

Tags: literature, repetition

What are the differences between "Repetition and Refrain in literature?

and I've looked up some of the examples and sometimes they both hard to recognize which one is Repetition and Refrain.
How do i distinguish it?

Comment: I'd say that 'Literature' is the appropriate SE site for this question. The terminology is subject-specific.

Comment: _Refrain_ brings to mind _song_ or _poetry_, in which some words or lines are repeated. Repetition can be _anything_ that is repeated, even letters, concepts or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repetition is a very general term, but refrain is more specific.

**Repetition** of any sounds or words can create a rhythm, sort of a drumming effect due to the repeat. *A stitch in time saves nine* barely rhymes but the repeated 'i' is pleasant to the ear. *Live and let live* gives us repetition of the 'l' sound.

**Refrain** is usually that last line that shows up each time in a poem or song verse —that's the part called the refrain.

> The answer, my friend, is blowing in the wind...
>
> Que sera, sera

[American Heritage definition:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/refrain) A phrase, verse, or group of verses repeated at intervals throughout a song or poem, especially at the end of each stanza.

Answer (score -1):

Refrain is actually repetition of same line in a speech or in a poesy.
Whereas repetition is word repeating in a line.