# ostinato in literature; word for repeated phrase

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine every chapter of a book ends with a very similar passage.

Is there a word that encapsulates this writing technique?

An ostinato in music is (as far as I understand it, I'm no expert) a musical phrase that will be heard often repeated throughout a piece. The music keeps coming back to it.

I would like to describe a phrase/passage/block of text that the larger text keeps returning to.

What's a word for this?

Comment: I think the literary device  you are looking for is ***Repetition***: https://literarydevices.net/repetition/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @user121863 that the example you give is certainly a type of *repetition*, and I would cite the same source ([literarydevices.com](https://literarydevices.net/repetition/)).

I would just go a step farther to be a bit more specific. *Repetition* is a term that covers a full set of different literary devices. Most of these describe using repetition within a particular sentence, paragraph, or verse.

I think that ***refrain***, which is a particular kind of *repetition*, may suit your purpose.

The term *refrain* is most commonly used for poetry or songs, when a particular line or phrase is repeated regularly, at the end of multiple stanzas or verses, or between them ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/refrain)).

But it can also be used in prose. From [litcharts.com](https://www.litcharts.com/literary-devices-and-terms/refrain): "The term *refrain* has come to have a meaning that is a bit different, and less specific, in the context of speeches or prose writing. In such writing, a *refrain* refers simply to any phrase or sentence that is regularly repeated."

So for the phenomenon you're describing, I'd suggest ***refrain***, which is a type of *repetition*.

Comment: By the way, the distinction between _refrain_ and _repetition_ has been dealt with before on the site: see [Repetition and refrain in literature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375116/repetition-and-refrain-in-literature), but the use of _refrain_ in prose is not dealt with specifically. Another question, [Term for rhetorical refrain](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/465944/term-for-rhetorical-refrain/465947#465947), dealt with speeches.